# Guid column in model, what is the migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a column/property in my Model that is a GUID?

What would my migration look like for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example storing the GUID in a string: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=104690#p104690 (`unique_identifier`in the migration should be renamed `uuid` to concord with the model validations).